# Correlations within Factor in a psychometric measurement instrument

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, psychometrics

I am working with results of a psychometric test. There are twelve factors and each have three subfactors. My problem is that one of the subfactors correlates very highly 0.3 to 0.7 with subfactors of other factors in fact with all but 10 of 36. And this is a consistent observation across three healthy samples, n1=427, n2= 353 and n3=945. Though this can be explained by looking at the meaning of these traits. But, should it question the robustness of the factor structure or the instrument? Additionally intra factor correlations are also low and insignificant at many instances.

Please note that this is a very well researched and well known psychometric instrument.

Need help with interpreting this information. Any ideas, what I should make of this observation?

Added this for additional information:

Not really, measurement model does shown some strong correlations for the subfactor outside its own factor (3 such correlations are strong), none of which are more than o.5. In my samples I consistently see two correlations at 0.7 and two others at 0.6 (I see 23 of 36 correlations above 0.3). I wish I could share the correlations here, but the information is proprietary. And the subfactor has very low  correlation with another subfactor within its own factor. These others are very high as compared with the correlations given in the manual. Could it be a sampling error? What inferences can I draw for the samples if these correlations are exaggerated (more than what was seen in the norm group)?

Comment: Does the measurement model specify that those factors should not correlate? How about the higher-order factors: are they intended to correlate? Does the problematic factor at least correlate more strongly with other factors that share its higher-order factor? If these factors are supposed to be less correlated, it sounds like a problem for discriminant validity, but if correlation is intended, it could be good news. It's probably not possible to determine whether the model or the instrument is more flawed from what you've said here. That would depend more on how the instrument was designed.

Comment: Is you data set in stone.  There are approaches to augment existing experimental design that allow you to confirm or reject a particular relationship between variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a problem. All sub scales are usually correlated on a health measurement scale. There are measures called item-total correlations where you delete an individual item from a subscale and correlate the item with all subscales. In general, the individual item should correlate most with the subscale it was deleted from and not the others. You can also check Cronbach's alpha within subscales against generally agreed acceptable levels. Lastly, you could apply a confirmatory factor analysis to the data to confirm the subscales exist.

Comment: Cronbach alphas are healthy as per the manual. They are all in the range of 0.7-0.9. And are stronger with in factor even in samples. Could this be a sampling problem, after all these results are not shown in norm group. But again how can the same error be replicated in three different samples?